# Install Win32 X64 VSCode 1.15.1 from .zip

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-code

I don't have admin rights on my Windows 7 system, so I installed Win X64 VSCode 1.15.1 from the `VSCode-win32-x64-1.15.1.zip` by unpacking into the `MyDocuments` path and placing a link on the Start Menu. This download was smaller and I have a slow connection.

However, since there was no installation program, there is no registration of components in the registry and no listing in ***Programs & Features*** to make a future uninstall convenient.

Is there a 'register' script somewhere to make this type of portable install more permanent?

Answer (score 0):

Unzipping to a folder is not the same as installing a program. No entries for Programs & Feature are registered.

If you wish to associate file types to an unregistered program though, you simply navigate to the executable for that program when choosing the program you wish to associate with the file type.

1. Right-click on a file of the type you wish to associate and click **Open With...**
2. Select the checkbox **Always use this app to open... files**
3. Click **More Apps** and then **Look For Another App On This PC**
4. Browse to the folder you extracted VSCode to and select **Code.exe** and click Open.

If you wish for a more "permanent" install than that, speak with your IT staff about installing the application using admin credentials, which, frankly, is probably where you should have started.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no simple way to uninstall the program that you download as a zip. Even if VSCode does not creates files outside your `User` folder, there will be lots of registry keys, and they will be left behind when you delete the folder where you extracted the zip file.

One way to manually check the registry keys created is to use [RegMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/regmon) or [ProcessMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to inspect the execution of VSCode. It will monitor all registry keys created, changed or queried, so you can later delete them all.  Process Monitor can show you the files too, so you can delete them later.

It's not easy, but can be done.